# Laravel QueryBuilder return array of values

Tags: laravel

In my application, there are two models:

- person
- subject

there's a many-to-many relationship between those two.

In order to fetch all people (person) with their respective subjects, I do;

```
   $people = Person::with(['subjects' => function($query) {
     $query->select('id');
   }]);
```

Results in:

```
{
            ...

            "subjects": [
                {
                    "id": 16
                },
                {
                    "id": 21
                },
                {
                    "id": 32
                }
            ],
},
```

I am wondering is there an elegant way to get an array of subject ids instead:

```
{
            ...

            "subjects": [
                10,
                14,
                21,
                38
            ],
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map) collection method. I've just tested this solution with many-to-many relationship and it works fine:

```
$collection->map(function ($i) {
    $i->subjectArray = $i->subjects->pluck('id')->toArray();
    unset($i->subjects);
    return $i;
});
```

Comment: Thought about looping through the collection, wondered if there's a more elegant solution

Comment: @YonatanNaxon you could use your own method instead of `with()` to load related data (or your own collection method), but this is a bad idea for many reasons. I wouldn't recommend you modify collection at all, but if you need to, using `map()` is the best solution here.